# Which docker base image will best suite for deploying AEM_6.4_Quickstart JAR file?

Tags: docker, osgi, containers, aem, osgi-bundle

I am exploring an option to deploy AEM_6.4_Quickstart JAR file using DOCKER.

I am aware that Adobe does not officially support Docker containers for AEM Quickstart jar.

I tried using nimmis/java-centos:openjdk-8-jdk as my base docker image, with which I was able to run the docker on my local.

Also I logged into localhost:4502 to download and install "Forms Add-on 6.4" package for working with OutputService and FormsService.

Everything seems to be working fine when working on local machine.

When I deploy this docker container on cloud, I am facing a very random issue of "/crx-quickstart/bedrock/svcnative/XMLFormService/XMLFormService.exe" is not found.

I am confused on why is this issue occurring.

Now I wanted to do a trial on changing the base image, but would like to get clarity on which base docker image will best suite for AEM_6.4_Quickstart jar.

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.. The 64 bit version of centOS were missing few libraries. I included two commands "RUN yum -y install glibc.i686, RUN yum -y install libX11.i686" in my Dockerfile and everything started working fine :) Thank you for your valuable time